# Creating new rails project throws exception when installing json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-8.1, devkit, railsinstaller

I'm kind of newbie in ruby and I'm trying to create a new project in my Win8.1 pc.

I'm using the latest rails installer. The installations ends successfully but when  I run rails new my_project I got this error when it is Installing json.

```
Installing json (1.8.1) creating Makefile
      0 [main] make 5852 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    439 [main] make 5852 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
MSYS-1.0.17 Build:2011-04-24 23:39
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=10002840
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=75BE6DB4 edx=00000003 esi=00000024 edi=00000001
ebp=0028D638 esp=0028D4A0 program=C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin\make.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
```

I've try installing as administrator, compatibility mode (win7) and replacing DevKit but nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are using rails on windows its obvious that you will have to face so many issues with gems installation, etc. I suggest you to switch to Unix-based system as suggested by Serge Vinogradoff.

If you still wants to continue with windows then you need to check if c compiler is installed on your machine properly or not. If not then RubyInstaller Development Kit may help you: http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

The devkit installs a C-compiler (and some other stuff) to compile C-written parts.

Install it and try again to install the gem - perhaps with option --platform=ruby.

Also you can try to use [json_pure](http://rubygems.org/gems/json_pure) written on pure Ruby

Comment: Details of devkit can be found at https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: Thanks for your help but I already changed the default devkit installed and the one downloaded from rubyinstaller. I think I will moving to Ubuntu XD.

Comment: Yep Ubuntu is good idea. Many programs you will work with don't work on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to switch to Unix-based system if you want to work with Rails.